# Align Class containing a class

Tags: html, css

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfUzr.jpg)

I want to set the class first to the right of the class second containing form . I want to keep the class first  inside the form that is below **Please share your experience**. I can do that be using margin left and margin right. How to achieve this using floats or any other way.

```css
body, select, input, textarea, button, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Hind;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="tel"], input[type="date"], textarea {
   
    margin-left: 0px; 
}

input:focus { 
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid green;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
textarea:focus {
        outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
#exitpopup-modal .modal-body {
    padding:0px;
}
.modal-body {
  
     padding: 0px; 
}
.first
{
margin-left:12%;}
.second img {
   width: 369px;
     height: 404.6px;
    margin-top: -1%;
}
.second form{
display:table;
margin-left: 37px;
margin-top: 29px;
 
}
.row1{
 
 font-size: 10px;
    font-family: inherit;
     display: table-row;
border: 2px solid red;
}
.row1 #name,#mail,#contact{
    
  
     color:black;
 width: 260px;
 height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border-radius:3.9px;
    border-color: #777;
display:table-cell;
} 
.row1 textarea{
  width: 260px;
  height: 110px;
               color:black;
               border-color: #777;
display:table-cell;
}
.row1 #submit{
width:152px;
height: 44px;
margin-left:15%;
background-color:#337ab7;
color:white;   
 border-color:none;
}
.row1 #submit:hover{
width:152px;
height: 44px;
margin-left:15%;
background-color:white;
color:#337ab7;   
 border-color:none;
}
.second,.first{
    float: left;
}
.clearfix{
    clear:both
}
.titan{
text-align:center;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="second">
   <form id="form" name="theform" action="javascript:myformsubmit()">

  <div class="row1">

<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name *" required><br><br>
</div>
  <div class="row1">

<input type="email" id="mail"  placeholder="Your email *"  required><br><br>
</div>
  <div class="row1">

<input id="contact" type="number" placeholder="Your  phonenumber*" required><br><br>
</div>
  <div class="row1">
 
<textarea  id="reason" rows="5" placeholder="Any reason to leave ?*" required></textarea><br><br>

</div>
<div class="first">
  <input type="radio" name="experience" value="I am happy and purchased/will purchase" checked> I am happy and purchased/will purchase<br>
  <input type="radio" name="experience" value="You are not selling in my city"> You are not selling in my city<br>
  <input type="radio" name="experience" value="You do not have the product i am looking for"> You do not have the product i am looking for<br>
  <input type="radio" name="experience" value="I find your prices higher than market"> I find your prices higher than market<br>
</div>


  <div class="row1">

<input id="submit"   type="submit" value="Submit" > 
</div>

</form>
    </div>


 <div class="titan">Please share your experience </div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that so you want the .first to stay inside the .second div and you want to get it 'out' of the class .second ? or you just want .first to stay inside the .second but to float right ?

Comment: i have added an image it is more clear there what i want to achieve@edisoni.1337

Comment: Check my answer because it works :) and i see that you are new here but when someone shows the correct way to fix your problem you should mark as correct answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2u84p5Lg/6/). When you are in small screens you should use `@media` queries to change your `input` width and it will work even in mobile screen.

```
#form , .first{
  display:inline-block;
}
.first{
  float:right;
  margin:25px;
}
```

Comment: i wanted the radio types  to be inside form@edisoni.1337

Comment: Then you should check your html code and update in your question

Comment: i hav updated please neglect for previous one @ edisoni.1337

Comment: submit button should be at last @edisoni.1337

Comment: Did it worked as you expected ? If yes vote up and choose as correct please :)